# Trying to add a image to a group box, however, it doesnt show up

Tags: c#, image, groupbox

Solved: Using design toolbox.

I'm using the following method to add a image

```
    private void cobertura1vertente_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox pb1 = new PictureBox();
        pb1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:/cobertura1vertente.png");
        pb1.Location = new Point(3, 3);
        pb1.Size = new Size(250, 250);
        //doubt right below
        groupBox81.Controls.Add(pb1);

    }
```

I usually would add a image to a entire form, but now i want to add it to a specific groupbox, who lies inside a tab.

If the code is correct, my guess is that the location that i've set is relative to the whole form, and not to the groupBox, why would that happen?

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? Do you really have image in the _root_ of the C drive?

Comment: @PMF 100% sure, i used the same code with a file on c:/ just for testing purposes and it worked, but it was for a entire form and therefore i used `this.Controls.Add(pb1);` Now i want it in that groupbox, and i'm guessing i'm doing something wrong, because even with a more appropriate location the image doesnt show up.

Comment: Each Control's Location is relative to its Parent, in this case the GroupBox. Your code works just fine, with a valid Path. Your Path probably ought to be: "C:\\cobertura1vertente.png"

Comment: I remember having had some issues with placing items below tab panels, but that was not with recent WinForms versions. Is there a reason you're not just placing the picture box in design mode and show it when required?

Comment: @TaW Hi again! It doesn't, I'm placing this code after `Public Form1() { //regular code } //cobertura1vertente_Load` could the image be lacking because of it? It's a completely separated method that i don't call.

Comment: @PMF No, i looked for a code to insert pictures and that one seemed right trough. It worked and so i was fine with it, but after your comment i tried the design tool and it works fine now, and its much easier :) Thank you

Comment: ?? What do you mean it is in a code that you don't call??

Comment: @TaW: I guess he didn't call it on his own. It's obviously(?) an event handler generated by "hidden" code.

Comment: Usually you create methods to do repetitive stuff, nevermind, i mean't i don't recall the code again, but the same happens with buttons or checkboxes (I'm really new to all this) So i thought I'd have to call it somewhere, but it's not the case i guess.